# PostgreSQL Btree index on top of Unique index

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I have a table with a unique index.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX task_index ON public.task USING btree (id, user);
```

Most of my selects are using where id=?

So do I still need an index on ID column?  Or the unique index itself indexed the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique index you already created uses a B tree with `id` as the first field to split with.  This index should be usable for a where clause containing either only `id` or `id` and `user`.  For the former case, consider a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM task
WHERE id = 3;
```

Postgres can use your current index to find the subtree which corresponds to `id = 3`.  For all leaf nodes beneath this subtree, it can simply scan to find all matching records.

Comment: Thank you so much, the same index will work if I do where  `user='something'`

Comment: Nope.  That can't use your index (or at least it is unlikely the index would be used).